# Defer loading jquest and customer .js file (Using google snippet)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, internet-explorer-8, load

Google tells us we should defer loading of jquery until after the page has loaded.
I took the sample code that Google provides and modified it slightly so that the jquery library is loaded, a callback is invoked and my own custom .js file is then loaded.

It's pretty straightforward stuff.
Seems to work on FireFox, does not work on IE8.

My question:

Is there anything in the code that IE8 would not support.
(i.e. why is this code not running on IE8)

Thanks for your ideas.

David

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function downloadJSAtOnload()
{

getScript("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js",function(){  
getScript("/course/java/linguashop2013.js", function() {});
});

}

function getScript(url,callback)
{
var element = document.createElement("script"); 
element.src = url; 
document.body.appendChild(element); 
element.onload=callback;
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older IE there's no `load` event for `script` tags.

This article explains how to load scripts properly:
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/

Comment: Script tags at the bottom is not really the answer.  Google is providing the above code and telling us all to load the scripts async after the page has loaded.

Comment: Read the article again. Read what is you problem.
If that still doesn't help, I can't help you.